# Getting and posting the value of a select dropdown with dynamic id with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is my first time here. Thank you for the opportunity to be part of this community.

I have a PHP code that generate a table with data from mySQL database. It will list:

```
$output .='<tr id="'.$id.'">';
$output .='<td>'.$agency.'</td>';
$output .='<td>'.$contact.'</td>';
$output .='<td align="left">'.$telephone.'</td>';
$output .='<td align="left">'.$email.'</td>';
$output .='<form name="seleciona" id="seleciona">';
$output .='<td align="left"><select id="ativo" name="ativo">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="1">Active</option>
                        <option value="2">Pending</option>
                        <option value="3">Suspended</option>
                </select>
    <img class="apply" src="../images/apply.png" width="16" height="16"></td>';

$output .='</form>';
$output .='</tr>';
```

Then I would like to send the selected option in the select dropdown box through jQuery
to a PHP file called post_status.php when user click on the image apply.png. Everything is working, the only problem is to get the value of the selected box and send it together with the id to the PHP page.

This is the jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('#table2 td img.apply').click(function(){
    if (confirm("Do you want to change this status?")) {
      var parent = $(this).closest('TR');
      var id = parent.attr('id');

      var activation ---> here should be the code to catch up the selected value

      $.post("post_activation.php", { id: id, activation: activation } );
      alert("Status has been updated!"+id+activation);
  }
  return false;
});
});
</script>
```

and finally the file post_activation.php

```
<?php
include "../connect_to_mysql.php";

if(isset($_POST['id'])){    
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $activation=$_POST['activation'];

  $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE agencies 
                    SET 
                    active='$activation', 
                    last_update=CURDATE() 
                    WHERE 
                    id='$id'")or die(mysql_error()); 

}
?>
```

Comment: It would appear you're outputting MULTIPLE of these table rows with selects? An `id` **MUST** be unique across the whole document. If you're repeating this html snippet even ONCE, producing 2+ selects, you're going to get bad results.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem related to activation?

Comment: Hi Jonas92. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I just have a table that lists data from MySQL. One of the columns is a select drop down that offers 3 options to the user. 1 - Active, 2- Pending, 3 - Suspended. This select will be listed in each line along with the respective record. I would be able to select a status and have it updated in the related record at the database through jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `<select id="ativo'.$id.'" name="ativo">` as HTML portion.
And in jQuery portion `var activation = $("#ativo"+parent.attr('id')).val();`

There's your answer...

Comment: How do I close this question as answered?

Comment: Most Welcome Alex... If you find this working for you, you can up vote and can tick the right mark below it..

Answer (score 0):

This should work to find the currently selected value:

```
var element = document.getElementById("ativo");
var selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
activation = selected;
```

You can also take a look at [this demonstration](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_index)

Comment: but how do I get the selected value from the drop down box to a variable just like I did with the id? I gave an fix id to the selected box. Is this right or do I have to give it a dynamic id just like I did with the TR?

Comment: .on("click" --- works fine. I can get the TR id! Very good. The only problem now is to get the current line select box id!

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope I'm understanding you correctly now.

Answer (score -1):

```
var activation = $("#ativo").html(); // gives you Active,Pending,Suspended
```

OR

```
var activation = $("#ativo").text(); // gives you Active,Pending,Suspended
```

And

```
var activation = $("#ativo").val(); // gives you 1,2,3
```

Comment: I used the third option but looks like it is getting only the value of the first line. I've tried to change the value of the second line and it got the select box value of the first and replaced the second with it. Probably this is happening because the id of the object doesn't look dynamic.

Comment: He wants to find the currently selected option, not all of them.